# How to extract a, b of johnsonsu.rvs() distribution from the first four moments mean, stdev, skewness and kurtosis?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy.stats

So let's see that I have a code where:

```py
mu=0 # first moment
rms=3 # second moment
skew=1 # third moment - skewness
kurt=3 # fourth moment - kurtosis
```

The problem is that I want to use these parameters as input and extract from them some `a, b` to feed my `johnsonsu.rvs(a=?, b=?, loc=mu, scale=rms, size=[N,N])`. I know that there is a way to derive the moments from `a` and `b`, but is there any way to do the opposite? (Probably it is just trivial math to do that, but I cannot understand).

I am translating a MATLAB code to python, where such distributions as johnsonsu, are derived from the first four moments, so there is no other way to do that.

Comment: Did you try with `tensorflow`? https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/substrates/jax/distributions/JohnsonSU .Also, can you post the plot and data of the MATLAB pdf?

Comment: There's another problem, in `scipy` for `johnsonsu` parameters `loc` and `scale` are not the mean and StdDev but xi and lambda. So it is basically parametrized on gamma (`a`), delta (`b`), xi (`loc`) and lambda (`scale`).

Comment: There is a toolbox in MATLAB to get gamma, delta, xi, lambda from mu, sd, skew, kurt https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46123-johnson-curve-toolbox

Comment: It is a code related to surface simulation in nanometrology. Probably if I upload it, I will make the things more complicated. But the main reason why I want to do that in this way is because before of JohnshonSU simulation, I do a Gaussian simulation which uses the first four moments. After that I use it to produce non-Gaussian surfaces. All the papers about surface simulations use the first four moments.

Comment: I want to translate it to python, because I want to use this simulation to do machine learning. Python is the best language for me for machine learning, and apart from that I have Linux and the only way to run MATLAB is from OCTAVE. If there is any way to combine MATLAB or OCTAVE and python would be helpful.

Comment: Is there any way to inverse the function `stats(a, b, loc=0, scale=1, moments=’mv’)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231735/discussion-between-cybermathidiot-and-max-pierini).

Comment: Thank you very much brother! You are a God!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ported the MATLAB code to estimate Johnson distributions parameters from moments

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46123-johnson-curve-toolbox

to Python

https://github.com/maxdevblock/j_johnson_M

Usage

```
from j_johnson_M import f_johnson_M

coef, j_type, err = f_johnson_M(mu, sd, skew, kurt)

gamma, delta, xi, lam = coef
```